# Javascript dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to create dropdown menu that will open and collapse when the "mobile-nav" button gets clicked.

Please see this video or website as examples of the intended behavior:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozOSV75DgzU
- http://travisneilson.com/

```js
function mobileNav() {
  $('.mobile-nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var status = $(this).hasClass('is-open');
    if (status) {
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').removeClass('is-open');
    } else {
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').addClass('is-open');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* ------------------------------------------ */

/* BASIC SETUP */

/* ------------------------------------------ */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  text-align: justify color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background: #333;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
/* ------------------------------------------ */

/* REUSABLE COMPONENTS */

/* ------------------------------------------ */

.row-basic {
  max-width: 1216px;
}
.main-container {
  max-width: 1216px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* ------------------------------------------ */

/* HEADER */

/* ------------------------------------------ */

.mobile-nav {
  display: ;
  position: ;
  width: 1216px;
  background: white;
  padding: 31px 0px 21px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
}
.mobile-nav.is-open {
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
.mobile-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.mobile-nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.mobile-nav ul li a:link,
.mobile-nav ul li a:visited {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header {
  background-color: rgba(246, 149, 149, 0.06);
  height: 81px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 24px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
/* ----- NAVIGATION -----*/

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
}
.main-nav {
  list-style: none;
}
.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 31px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
  padding-right: 9px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: auto;
}
.main-nav li:last-child {
  border-right: hidden;
  margin-right: 31px;
}
.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.user-tools {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.user-tools:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/* ----- MENU BUTTON -----*/

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 31px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mobile-nav-toggle span,
.mobile-nav-toggle span::before,
.mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.mobile-nav-toggle span::before {
  top: 11px;
}
.mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
  bottom: 17px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="resources/js/functions.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="mobile-nav is-open">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <header class="row-basic">
      <nav>
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="user-tools">
        <div class="mobile-nav-toggle">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to add link to jQuery script.
2. Delete declaration function mobileNav() { and it closing braket }.

   ```
   $('.mobile-nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      var status = $(this).hasClass('is-open');
      if (status) {
         $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').removeClass('is-open');
      } else {
         $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').addClass('is-open');
      }
   });
   ```

Here is example of working code      https://jsfiddle.net/efjz40ob/

Comment: wow thank you very much for taking time, but i can't seem to make it work on my PC, i did delete the "declaration function mobileNav() { and it closing braket }" just like you have suggested, NOT sure i'm adding the link to jQuery script, 

COULD you please wright me the link to jQuery? Please?

name of that js file is "functions.js" and its in the same directory with index

Comment: Sorry if I bother you, I'm new to javascript :-), PLEASE tell me again what I should change or add in details PS: that jQueary script don't know how to, I appreciate your answers :-)

Comment: OK so I've solved it, it works now, the problem was i added js script before jQuery, it's supposed to be after. BUT now i have different problem, the code seems to work fine via brackets but if i open index.html outside brackets then the nav bar doesnt work again BUT its works fine inside brackets editor, ANY IDEAS WHAT IT CAN BE CAUSING it?

Comment: Can you paste somethere you code? I'm not shure what you mean in "open index.html outside brackets"? If you paste javascript code into index.html you have to wrap it inside <script type="text/javasript"> ///code here </script>

Comment: OH the code is the same, what i meant by "open index.html outside brackets", when I load index.html + css + js file into Brackets Code Editor and open from there then the menu is working 

BUT

IF I don't use Brackets Code Editor at all and instead go to the directory folder where the website is saved and double click index.html then the navigation menu is not working. ANY IDEAS WHY?

Comment: Have you added link to jquery library to index.html? Link like this <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: here are the files download it from my dropbox 

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hx8jfquynv8ar07/AACXG4BMEMj1enjfoN3aZtsIa?dl=0

Comment: I've changed the link to jquery to <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> and it works now - warning - parser its out HTTPS: at the beginning of the URL

Comment: IT WORKS WHEN ITS LIKE THIS:

http://127.0.0.1:58200/index.html

BUT IT DOESNT WORK WHEN ITS LIKE THIS:

file:///C:/Users/miro/Desktop/test/index.html

Comment: I have uploaded the website on my server and it works as well

BUT

why it doesnt work when i open from the folder directory...then it looks like this: file:///C:/Users/miro/Desktop/test/index.html

Comment: ANY ideas why its doing?, why it needs http to work?

Comment: If it working on your webserver bot not on pc then something wrong with you pc, may be firewoll or something

Comment: NO my pcs are fine, when i open the index.html from folder directory i get this address: file:///C:/Users/miro/Desktop/test/index.html ...AND when I get this address then it doesnt work...so I have to open it with a code editor and then it works OR upload it on a webhosting server

Comment: ANYWAY thank you for your time, NOW I have another question regarding this website, do you want to help me with it? If yes should I create a new topic section?

Comment: Of course you have to create a new topic. Post me the link to see if I can help

Comment: HEY Trike, can you look at my topic and give me vote up for my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947655/change-hamburger-button-color