# How to change span color on div hover

Tags: css, button, colors, swap, onhover

I am trying to change color of span on div's hover

How to make the red hamburger button (which is span) to change the color to black on div's hover

PS: Right now it does it on span's hover

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjjbqct8/

```css
.mobile-nav-toggle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    background: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer; }
    .mobile-nav-toggle span,
    .mobile-nav-toggle span::before,
    .mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
        border-radius: 2px;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 6px;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(177, 66, 66, 0.8);
        position: relative; }
    .mobile-nav-toggle span::before {
        top: 11px; }
    .mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
        bottom: 17px; }
        .mobile-nav-toggle span:hover,
        .mobile-nav-toggle span:hover:before,
        .mobile-nav-toggle span:hover:after {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav-toggle">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hover psuedo selector for div instead span.

This is the selector you need to use

```
    .mobile-nav-toggle:hover span,
    .mobile-nav-toggle:hover span::before,
    .mobile-nav-toggle:hover span::after {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/gq2ey0ry/) is fiddle.

Comment: Thank you Laxmikant Dange, 

May I ask why you have included 2 columns next to each other instead of only 1. 

Because it works with only one column as well. 

Can you give me vote up please?

Comment: Hey Laxmikant Dange, how do you do a line brake when you write a comment? Thank you

Comment: @sparrow, Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter

Comment: Thank you, i get it now double column is css3 attribute, Hey how do you do a line brake when you write a comment?

Comment: @sparrow, Is this about stackoverflow comments?? then you can ask this question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. 


Actually I am also not aware of this. :P

Comment: What I mean is when you wrote you answer you put a line brake between your two sentences. How did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `hover` rules,

from this:

```
.mobile-nav-toggle span:hover,
.mobile-nav-toggle span:hover:before,
.mobile-nav-toggle span:hover:after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
}
```

to this:

```
.mobile-nav-toggle:hover span,
.mobile-nav-toggle:hover span:before,
.mobile-nav-toggle:hover span:after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
}
```

Reason: When you create a rule on `hover` of `span` and its pseudo-elements, only the ones you hover over will apply the styles. What you need is to create a rule on the `div` so that whenever you `hover` on that `div` the children get the styles.

Comment: Thank you Abhitalks, your answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Can you give me vote up please? It helps, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

this will work,

```
.mobile-nav-toggle:hover span,
.mobile-nav-toggle:hover span:before,
.mobile-nav-toggle:hover span:after,
.mobile-nav-toggle span:hover,
.mobile-nav-toggle span:hover:before,
.mobile-nav-toggle span:hover:after {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
```

Comment: Thank you Sanjay Bhardwaj, your answer does the job as well, It's not as elegant as Abhitalks's AND Laxmikant Dange'e answers but on other hand it gives me an idea how to change color of div and span separately

Can you give me vote up please?

Comment: Thank you too, i have learnt about two separate management on hover. I voted you.